# Use only numeric columns from DataFrame in a function

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that consists of some numeric and some non numeric columns

I tried to pipe only the numeric columns into a shapiro wilk test to see what statistical test to perform on them but I can't get it to work

```
CRF %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% shapiro.test()
```

Returns

```
Error in shapiro.test(.) : is.numeric(x) is not TRUE
```

I think it is because at the end I am still passing a list. But when I try to deconstruct it with unlist or to just run lapply on it still won't work.

My end goal is a vector containing all the names of all the values that are non-normal according to the shapiro wilk test so I can pass it later on into the function doing the statistical analysis.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to apply `shapiro.test` to each column separately? You can try `map_if`

```
purrr::map_if(CRF, is.numeric, shapiro.test)
```

Or in base R using `lapply` :

```
lapply(CRF[sapply(CRF, is.numeric)], shapiro.test)
```